# Saving Google map Points to a database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, google-maps-api-3

i have been playing with the Google maps trying to make a tour and save the start end and the way points in a database.

here is the java-script code that i use to pass the values

```
 function saveRoute() {

    var name = "<?php Print($log_username);?>";
    var waypts = [];
    var end = points.length-1;
    var dest = points[end].LatLng;
    if (document.getElementById("roundTrip").checked) {
      end = points.length;
      dest = points[0].LatLng;
    }
    data.start = {'lat': points[0].LatLng.lat(), 'lng': points[0].LatLng.lng()}
    data.end = {'lat': dest.lat(), 'lng':dest.lng()}

    for (var i=1; i<end; i++) {
        waypts[i-1] = [points[i].LatLng.lat(),points[i].LatLng.lng()]
        data.waypoints = waypts;
    }

    var str = JSON.stringify(data)

    var jax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    jax.open('POST','process.php');
    jax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    jax.send('command=save&mapdata='+str)
    jax.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(jax.readyState==4) {
    if(jax.responseText.indexOf('bien')+1)alert('Updated');
    else alert(jax.responseText)
    }}
  }
```

here is my php processing.php

```
     <? 
        ob_start(); 
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');

        $data = $_REQUEST['mapdata'];

        echo $data;


        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('mapdir');

        if($_REQUEST['command']=='save')
        {

          $query = "update mapdir set value='$data'";
          if(mysql_query($query))die('bien');
          die(mysql_error());
        }

        if($_REQUEST['command']=='fetch')
        {
          $query = "select value from mapdir";
          if(!($res = mysql_query($query)))die(mysql_error());      
          $rs = mysql_fetch_array($res,1);
          die($rs['value']);        
        }
      ?>
```

i always get the ajax response as "updated" but nothing happens to the database
where i have gone wrong ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ)

Comment: Please add the layout of your database tables to your question.

Comment: @LightningDust database have the table mapdir. it only contains id,value

Comment: @Fracsi i tried using mysqli but the same thing

Comment: @KelumAnthony You update the whole table, not just one row. You need something like: `UPDATE mapdir SET value='$NEW_VALUE' WHERE id='$SOME_ID'`.